# Dynamically create executing code in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

So, I have strange question (maybe so stupid), but...
So, my task.
I have same class which gives me same functionality. So, in the main program, which I realize (yes, it's client-server app)) , I want to dynamically create ".exe wrapper" for this class - simplest code like this:

```
class Program
{
    private SameClass mySameClass;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mySameClass = new mySameClass(args);
        Console.Readline();
    }
}
```

**In general, I want to create main app which creates slaves in the independent proccesses via dynamically code generation.**
So, how to make it and control it?
Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ It doesn't matter, I think. Same class which does same things - calculation, client part functionality, etc. I need to have main app which create slaves in the independent proccesses with the code I've written earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution based on CodeDom. Yes, It doesn't need reflection, sorry.
Code example:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
            parameters.CompilerOptions = "/platform:x64";
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
                                    @"using System;
                                     class Program {
                                           public static void Main(string[] args) {
                                           Console.WriteLine(""Hello world!"");
                                           Console.ReadLine();
                                           }
                                      }");

            var testProcess = new Process();
            testProcess.StartInfo.FileName = results.CompiledAssembly.CodeBase;
            testProcess.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("I've run slave!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So SameClass is supposed to contain the same functions and functionality as the process you want to have run multiple times... I guess what you need are Threads.

Not too sure what you mean by dynamically but let's say you have an event that triggers whenever you need a new SameClass process. Just run

```
SameClass newClone = new SameClass(args);
Trhead _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(newClone.Start));
_trhead.Start();
```

You can probably do this a little more elegant and refactor within SameClass but it's pretty hard to understand your question, so I guess this is the best I can do you hopefully answer your question.

Comment: No, I need Process, not a Thread. It's connected with the fact, that SameClass works with class, which is a singleton...

Comment: What is the functionality you're looking for then? Why do you need a process and not a Thread? You're giving too little information! You said you need multiple subtasks running the same code, Threads do this, so elaborate on how this not satisfy your needs. If SameClass is a singleton, SameClass is a really confusing name for it.

Comment: I want to create main app which creates slaves in the independent proccesses via dynamically code generation. This is client-server app, client part use R.NET library, the main class of which - REngine - is a singleton. I need multiple independent instances of it - so, I need to create different proccesses for each client I run from main app (main app decorates REngine for user - it's an emulation of multithread REngine class).

Comment: @Dmitriy you are mixing up a lot of different things, using a lot of wrong names. And the question is *really* confusing. If you wanted to start multiple processes, just say that. Dynamic code, reflection etc are irrelevant. Besides, using multiple processes to speed up R is **not** as efficient as using a distribution that properly supports multicore and SSE operations. Revolution R's distribution does, achieving even 7x the speed of vanilla R on an i7

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  I know about RRO. I need multiple instances of R, created in different proccesses. I want to generate and control these proccesses from my main app. I want "one-run" app without any other handmade work - starting client parts manually and etc. It is hard? So, RRO don't have an abilities to use > 1 independent proccessor in the system, as I know. Also it cannot realize distributed computing.

Comment: You are wrong, or at least make wrong assumptions. RRO achieves this 7x speedup precisely because it *can* use multiple cores - an i7 has 4 of them. Or do you assume that multiple chips is somehow different than multiple cores? It isn't. As for processes - just look up the Process class. If you search for `Process` in SO, you'll find a *lot* of questions. I suggest you post a different question explaining what you actually want, in the question itself, not the comments. PS:  if RRO manages to use 70-80% of CPU, you won't achieve anything by starting another process

Comment: Can RRO work on clusters? This theme based on 2 themes connection - dynamical code generation (I need to create same code) and code execution in independents Processes (I need to execute code I've created earlier). I know how to work Process class. I tried to look for the information about this before I asked my question. This is offtop, I suppose, so I think, my sentence marked as bold in the question, gives enough information about problem I have. That's all.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos RRO, not RRO - who said that I'll use MKL and Intel processors? So, it could be any other client-server app. And who said that client code wouldn't consists of many control code, which not use multithreading via MKL? And who says that I'll use just only 1xN systems? It could be also MxN systems - M processors and N cores in each.